# [27759]: ERROR Failed to execute ban jail 'sshd' action in fail2ban log

Tags: debian, fail2ban

On my Debian 8 server, I see lots of this error in `fail2ban` log.

```
 [27759]: ERROR   Failed to execute ban jail 'sshd' action 'iptables-multiport' info 'ActionInfo({'ip': '1.1.2.2', 'fam
ily': 'inet4', 'ip-rev': '2.2.1.1.', 'ip-host': '210994.cloudwaysapps.com', 'fid': '1.1.2.2', 'failures': 3, 'time': 1547974803.0, 'matches': 'Jan 20 04:00:01
 chat sshd[1326]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=1.1.2.2 \nJan 20 04:00:03 chat sshd[1326]: Failed password f
or invalid user guest from 1.1.2.2 port 40633 ssh2', 'restored': 0, 'F-*': {'matches': ['Jan 20 04:00:01 chat sshd[1326]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure;
 logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=1.1.2.2 ', 'Jan 20 04:00:03 chat sshd[1326]: Failed password for invalid user guest from 1.1.2.2 port 40633 ssh2']
, 'failures': 3, 'mlfid': ' chat sshd[1326]: ', 'user': 'guest', 'ip4': '1.1.2.2'}, 'ipmatches': 'Jan 20 04:00:01 chat sshd[1326]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication
 failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=1.1.2.2 \nJan 20 04:00:03 chat sshd[1326]: Failed password for invalid user guest from 1.1.2.2 port 40633
 ssh2', 'ipjailmatches': 'Jan 20 04:00:01 chat sshd[1326]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=1.1.2.2 \nJan 20 04
:00:03 chat sshd[1326]: Failed password for invalid user guest from 1.1.2.2 port 40633 ssh2', 'ipfailures': 3, 'ipjailfailures': 3})': Error banning 1.1.2.2
2019-01-20 04:01:24,018 fail2ban.actions
```

I'm wondering what this error mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

possible reason: duplicate IP table chains (you need to check your roles), if this is the issue you can fix it be doing the following:

- stop f2b
- restart iptables
- backup your config-dir (/etc/fail2ban), just to compare (don't use it hereafter)
- uninstall f2b
- remove your config-dir (/etc/fail2ban),
  install f2b
- create your own fail2ban.local, jail.local and make there the changes, enable jails etc.

  - start f2b

Answer (score 0):

What's the location of "banaction"?

I changed the location of the "banaction" to default and succeeded.

Comment: and how does this answer the question?